# Как выровнять submit по центру при помощи Bootstrap-4?

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Как в данной форме, выровнять Submit посередине div блока при помощи bootstrap?

```html
<div class="form-group row pl-1">
  <div class = "col-sm-2">
    {{ Form::submit('Редактировать профиль', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary m-auto']) }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `margin:0px auto; padding:0px;`

Comment: @Arcadiy нужно средствами Bootstrap. Иначе какой смысл его использовать, если где то будет обычный css а где то он. Потом одни проблемы в правках будут

Comment: <div class = "col-sm-2 text-center">